# Laravel 5.7 en php 7.0 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

Tags: php, laravel, php7

tengo un proyecto en laravel 5.7 el problema que me trae acá, es que me han pedido subirlo y el servidor que me aportaron tiene instalado php 7.0 por lo que me lanza el error

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in home/laravel2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

Busque mucho en internet y encontré que la razón más probable para este error sea por la versión del php que como les digo es 7.0 siendo que laravel 5.7 exige un mínimo de php 7.1

Ya me han dicho que actualizar el php no es opción, por otros proyectos corriendo en el mismo servidor.

Trabajo para una empresa extranjera por lo que si ellos dicen que no cambiaran la versión del php yo debo solucionar desde acá.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué se puede hacer teniendo en cuenta que no puedes actualizar PHP a 7.1? Utilizar Laravel 5.5, el cual requiere php 7.0:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel miProyecto  "5.5.*" --prefer-dist
```

Es más fácil adaptar el código de tu proyecto, que intentar jugar con Laravel 5.7 en una versión de php 7.0 (sería bastante trabajo crear overrides o paquetes que permitan trabajar con php 7.0).

---

Para pasar de 5.7 a 5.5 en un proyecto existente, elimina la carpeta vendor y en tu composer.json confirma que la línea de Laravel aparezca así:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
```

Posteriormente ejecutas `composer install`.

Comment: vaya eso no implicaría de cierta forma hacerlo de nuevo? no dispongo de mucho tiempo, es decir, que tantas diferencias puedo encontrar entre ambas versiones de laravel?

Comment: No hay que hacerlo de nuevo, finalmente Laravel es solo una «dependencia» del proyecto. No son muchas las diferencias entre 5.5 y 5.7, al menos en mi opinión, podrías resolverlo en un par de días, máximo, a menos que sea un proyecto grande con 200 modelos, 100 controladores y otro montón de capas.

Comment: Ya edité mi pregunta para reflejar lo que debes hacer para pasar a 5.5 en tu proyecto actual.

Comment: mmm comprendo, lo voy a intentar, estoy creando un nuevo proyecto con el comando que me has dejado en tu respuesta, luego haré los cambios que me indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.7 tiene como requerido que la version de php 7.1.3. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#installing-laravel

No te va a dejar instalarla, y si lo hace con `composer install` se romperá en los archivos internos al intentar acceder a las funciones nuevas de php integradas en Laravel 5.7.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la pronta respuesta, lo que comentas lo se y lo entiendo, el caso es que este es un proyecto ya desarrollado, solo debo subir, pero el servidor que me han proporcionado tiene php 7.0 y mi jefe me dice que no lo puede actualizar porque otros proyectos dependen de él, mi verdadera pregunta es que puedo hacer, (si existe el modo) que laravel corra en el servidor teniendo esa versión de php